# Pod Init not creating a xcworkspace?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I've started a new Mac, ran sudo gem install cocoapods. Done pod init.  The Pod file is created but without the .xcworkspace file

Using Xcode 9.3

Any help appreciated.

Tried:
Uninstalling cocoapods and reinstalling with no luck.

Comment: pod init can't create .xcworkspace file that only creates pod file. pod install generate .xcworkspace file.

Comment: The `pod install` will create the .xcworkspace. The `pod init` will just create a `Podfile` file.

Comment: @Larme I'd suggest making this an answer.

Comment: Rookie mistake! Yes pod install does it.  Ooops.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `pod install` will create the `.xcworkspace`. 
The `pod init` will just create the Podfile file. –

At start:

```
>$ ls -la
drwxr-xr-x   5 ...  ...   170 12 avr 11:04 .
drwxr-xr-x  34 ...  ...  1156 12 avr 10:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x  12 ...  ...   408 12 avr 10:33 MyProjectName
drwxr-xr-x   5 ...  ...   170 12 avr 10:17 MyProjectName.xcodeproj
```

After `pod init`:

```
>$ pod init
>$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   5 ...  ...   170 12 avr 11:04 .
drwxr-xr-x  34 ...  ...  1156 12 avr 10:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x  12 ...  ...   408 12 avr 10:33 MyProjectName
drwxr-xr-x   5 ...  ...   170 12 avr 10:17 MyProjectName.xcodeproj
-rw-r--r--   1 ...  ...   254 12 avr 11:04 Podfile
```

=> File added: *Podfile*

After `pod install`:

```
>$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `MyProjectName.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 0 dependencies from the Podfile and 0 total pods installed.

[!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `11.2` on target `MyProjectName` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

>$ ls -la
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   8 ...  ...   272 12 avr 11:05 .
drwxr-xr-x  34 ...  ...  1156 12 avr 10:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x  12 ...  ...   408 12 avr 10:33 MyProjectName
drwxr-xr-x   5 ...  ...   170 12 avr 11:05 MyProjectName.xcodeproj
drwxr-xr-x   3 ...  ...   102 12 avr 11:05 MyProjectName.xcworkspace
-rw-r--r--   1 ...  ...   254 12 avr 11:04 Podfile
-rw-r--r--   1 ...  ...    77 12 avr 11:05 Podfile.lock
drwxr-xr-x   7 ...  ...   238 12 avr 11:05 Pods
```

=> File added: *MyProjectName.xcworkspace*, *Podfile.lock*, Folder added: *Pods*