# do people need pod init or pod install when they clone the project?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have a question about pod files. I'm writing a README, and I'm not sure if other people need to run pod init and pod install when they clone my project to their Xcode. I used three cocoapods, 'SwiftyJSON', 'Alamofire', 'Kingfisher'.

I just need to submit my project to other people and the app is not on the app store, so I want to know how they can run my project.

Comment: It depends, what do you commit? Minimum: pod file, and maybe the workspace, more info there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49792332/pod-init-not-creating-a-xcworkspace/49793339#49793339 on what's created on the command. But the best way to do so, is to clone it and try. But usually, for sharing, a pod install should be the only thing to do, with a workspace and a pod file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After downloading your project a user has to execute the command

```
pod install
```

---

Differences between init and install commands:

To create the PodFile, execute

```
pod init
```

To download all the dependencies defined in Podfile, execute

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

`pod init` is only used for initiating the pods, to install the pods for a project whether from a repo or clone all you will need is `pod install`. Just make sure you commit the pod files along with the project.