# cocoapods does not generate workspace

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad, cocoapods

I am trying to use cocoapods on one of my swift projects, and I have tried multiple times to add it to my project, but every time I set it up, the workspace file does not show up. I see the xcodeprojectfile, Podfile, and the Pods folder in my overall xcode project folder, but I do not see the .xcworkspace file. I have followed multiple tutorials, but every time the .xcworkspace does not show up. My MacOS version is 12.4 Monterey, Cocoapods version 1.11.3, and XCode version 13.4.1. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you install the pods?

Comment: please list out the commands you followed in terminal while installing pods

Comment: Which command did you try? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49793339/1801544 Did you do the `pod install`? Do you have any error when doing it? You can ad `--verbose` to your command if you want, but you need to share what are the output for which command...

Comment: @cora Yes I put pod 'Firebase/Core' in my podfile and saved that.

Comment: @Vikassaini I used Pod init to create my podfile in the project. It was able to do that successfully. I then put pod 'Firebase/Core' in the podfile, saved it, then I ran pod install. Pod install gives back 640 lines and says [NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

[IMPORTANT]
Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.

Comment: @Larme I used Pod init to create my podfile in the project. It was able to do that successfully. I then put pod 'Firebase/Core' in the podfile, saved it, then I ran pod install. Pod install gives back 640 lines and says [NOTE] You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries. Bug reports are welcome. For details: ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html [IMPORTANT] Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports. 

I did pod install --verbose but whatever response I get is only there for a split second and is deleted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69352212/you-may-have-encountered-a-bug-in-the-ruby-interpreter-or-extension-libraries